# How do I resolve merge conflicts using git rebase?

Tags: gitlab

I want to know how I can resolve merge conflict using git rebase? I use gitlab UI to create merge request. Currently its showing "There are merge conflicts". How to get rid of this error on UI so that the administrator of project merges the "merge request" from UI?

I have new branch called "feature/one" which I am trying to merge into "dev" and ran into conflict issue.

Any help, greatly appreaciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are alone working on the feature/one, you would rebase it on top of dev locally, resolve the conflict there (meaning locally on your machine) and force push.

That is

```
git switch feature/one
git rebase dev
# resolve conflicts
git push --force
```

That would update your merge request automatically.